# Category renders text when configurable products, product opens correct

Tags: category, configurable-product, magento-2.1.2

I'm encountering a problem somewhat difficult to describe, Google and the forum seems empty in answers...

When opening a category containing configurable products, the category opens as text only with the following error:

> ***Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Cataloginventory\Model\Stock\Item' not found in /home/my/domains/url/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93***

A product is displayed on the page as text, when clicked on the link to the product page => the product opens correct with the choices for the config options.

Recreating steps:

1. Category containing a configurable product:
   http://www.fietsenwinkelonline.be/fietshelmen.html
2. When clicked on the product:
   http://www.fietsenwinkelonline.be/test-fietsenwinkel-online-be.html

Creating configurable renders no error and handles perfect.

Any ideas where to look for the problem/source?

Thanks in advance!